# JQuery Select2 not initialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, jquery-select2

I have a big miss understanding with jQuery [select2](http://select2.github.io/)

I add the select2 to my dropdown list:

```
$('#PartnerAdresse_IdCountry').select2(); 
//#PartnerAddresse_IdCountry is filled with all countries
```

this is my dropdownlist with ASP MVC5 creation :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PartnerAdresse.IdCountry, ViewBag.Country as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "", new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:100%;" })
```

// the Viewbag is the filling of all country from the controller

but on my page, nothing appear, this is the code generated in my console :

```
<select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="Le champ Pays doit être un nombre." 
id="PartnerAdresse_IdCountry" name="PartnerAdresse.IdCountry" style="width:100%;">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="2">Afrique du Sud</option>
    <option value="3">Albanie</option>
.
.
.
</select>
```

I've also checked:

- No double id in the page
- other form are correctly generated with select2

I have a problem only with this field... somebody can help me?

---

**EDIT**
I've change, in my code, it's corrected write with select2 : $('#PartnerAdresse_IdCountry').select2();

but the problem is the same

Comment: Just change `$('#PartnerAdresse_IdCountry').select();` to `$('#PartnerAdresse_IdCountry').select2();`

Comment: Yes, sorry, i mistook, in my code, is : .select2()

Comment: I'm not sure a `.` dot in the name of the select is a valid markup. What happens if you replace the dot with an underscore (make the name same as id)

Comment: From all other dropdown, the select2 change the model name (PartnerAdresse.idCountry) and convert the . (dot) to a underscore to be use with jQuery by Id

Comment: do not use the "generated code" in the jquery selector. **use the native id**. Select2 will hide your select and create a new one on top of it. It will not change your id or names!!!

Comment: But what i don't understand, is until now, all my other dropdownlist is set like that's : 
 $("#ProjectFamily_IdInstitut").select2();

and declared in my page :

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProjectFamily.IdInstitut, ViewBag.InstitutList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)

And all works... just this IdCountry dropdown dosn't work. but i will try your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The function is `select2()` not `select()`. try below:

```js
$('#PartnerAdresse_IdCountry').select2();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://select2.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.1/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.1/select2.js"></script>

<select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="Le champ Pays doit être un nombre." 
id="PartnerAdresse_IdCountry" name="PartnerAdresse.IdCountry" style="width:100%;"><option value=""></option>
<option value="1">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="2">Afrique du Sud</option>
<option value="3">Albanie</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `select2()` method, & not `select().

Just change `$('#PartnerAdresse_IdCountry').select();` to `$('#PartnerAdresse_IdCountry').select2();` and you are done!

Comment: Sorry, this is a mistake... I edited now

My code have the select2() implement... it was a mistake about writting in this post... sorry

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after all this search, the problem was from my side.

My page is a modal view with 5 independent form (Ajax.BeginForm) and in another form, i used a hide form with the same value (PartnerAdress.IdCountry) and after comment the line, it's finally worked...

Sorry and thanks for the answers :)